# Switch Between two SSI's using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, static, include

got a problem with a static html page which is using server side includes.

the html of the ssi has a closing head tag and opening body tag

<-- ssi start

blah blah blah

< /head>

< body>

-->

is there any way to switch between two different SSI's where the tags cross boundries like this. i need to be able to do this for switching between mobile and desktop, and can not edit the SSI's. this is static HTML so the only way if there is one is using javascript?

Comment: how could javascript do anything? **SERVER**-side includes... by the time JS could do anything, the page has already left the server with whatever the SSI's were supposed to do long done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to load the page, parse/replace the ssi tags, and then insert the body in a div element. Current mobile frameworks do that to achive page transitions, for example https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions